# How to check if a file is an ascii text file - BASH SCRIPT

Tags: bash, scripting, ascii

I have a Bash script that runs 3 commands. The last file is called "junk1.txt" which I am worrying about. I want to make an addition to the check the if statement performs.  If the "junk1.txt" is an ASCII text file. How would I go about doing this?

```
./command1 > command1.txt

while read l;

do
    command2 > command2.txt

    while read m;

        do

            command3 junk.txt > junk1.txt 2>/tmp/err
            if [ -s /tmp/err ] #I WANT TO ADD ANOTHER CONDITION HERE
            then
                echo "not cracked"
            else
                echo "cracked"
                exit
            fi
        done < command2.txt

done < command1.txt
```

Comment: You can't check if it is. You can only check if it could be or could not be. It is whatever the author chose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `file` to test this:

For your use case replace your `if [ -s /tmp/err ]` line with:

```
if [ -s /tmp/err ] && [ "$(file junk1.txt)" = "junk1.txt: ASCII text" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [strings](http://www.linfo.org/strings.html) command:

```
if diff <(strings ascii.txt) ascii.txt; then ...
```